# How to determine the order of a differential equation when it's solution is given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We know how to find the solution of a given **Homogeneous linear equations with constant coefficients**.

In assignment I have to find the minimum possible order of a Homogeneous linear equations with constant coefficients having $x^2 sin x$ as a solution. I am really blank and have no idea how to proceed. Kindly help me. Any hint or solution will be helpful to me. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Lets try $y' + a y = 0$ where $a$ is some unknown constant. Insert $y = x^2\sin(x)$ and solve for $a$. That does not work ($a$ must be a function of $x$) so let's try the next simplest case: $y'' + ay' + by = 0$. If this would not work then go up in order.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to look at the problem.

Take the homogeneous linear differential equation $L(y)=0$ where $L$ has degree $n$ and real coefficients. The standard test solution for this is $y=e^{ax}$ giving a polynomial equation of $P(a)=0$ degree $n$ for $a$ with the same coefficients as $L$.

If all the roots of $P$ are simple roots then $y$ is a linear combination of simple exponentials. If the roots are not real, then they come in conjugate pairs $c+di, c-di$ and combining them gives terms involving $e^{cx}\sin dx$ and $e^{cx}\cos dx$.

If there is a double root $b$, the solution may involve a term of the form $(rx+s)e^{bx}$ and for a triple root you get a quadratic coefficient.

So you need your auxiliary equation to have the right triple root, which should be enough, with some thought, to solve the problem. In fact it gives a quicker and cleaner solution than taking the derivatives and eliminating by hand, though you might want to check that the solution you get by this means does work.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x) = x^2\sin x$ is the solution of a linear ODE with constant coefficiencts, then for some $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ you have ($.^{(n)}$ means $n$-th derivative here) $$
  a_1\cdot f^{(1)} + \ldots + a_n f^{(n)} = f.
$$

Now in your case $f^{(1)} = x^2\cos x + 2x\sin x$. Is there an $a_1$ such that $$
  a_1 x^2\cos x + a_12x\sin x = x^2\sin x  \quad ?
$$
If not, try $n=2,3,\ldots$ until you succeed.

Comment: Can we take a to be 0?

Comment: @AbhishekChandra If it suits your needs, you can call an expression like $f(t) = \ldots$ where neither $f$ nor anything that depends on $f$ like a derivative, antiderivative, etc appear in the $\ldots$ part a "Zero-order differential equation". But at best, this offers some notational convenience, and I don't see how this relates to the OP's question...

Answer (score 4):

If $$y=x^2\sin x$$ you then have $$y'=x^2\cos x+2x\sin x$$$$y''=-x^2\sin x+4x\cos x+2\sin x$$

Now you see that you will be getting terms $p(x)\cos x+q(x)\sin x$ where $p(x), q(x)$ are quadratic in $x$. You can see that you can use $z=y''+y$ to eliminate the term in $x^2\sin x$ (and there is no term in $x^2\cos x$*). But it is a question of how to eliminate the remaining terms. You need more derivatives.

*It is useful to note that $y$ and $z$ are odd functions of $x$, so first derivatives won't help, because the first derivatives will be even functions. This simplifies the work considerably.

Comment: Which means that you need $(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+1)^2y$ to cancel the terms with first and second degree polyomial factors and $(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+1)^3y$ to cancel everything.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can approach this way.

Think when we have term $sin x$ in solution of D.E. Yes,when we have complex pair of roots and solution looks like $e^{\alpha x}(C_1cos(\beta x)+C_2sin(\beta x))$.And,in this case order of D.E.is $2$.But we want $x^2 sinx$ to be present.

Now,suppose we have repeated pair of complex root.This means our solution will look like$e^{\alpha x}((C_1 + C_2 x)cos(\beta x)+(C_3 + C_4 x)sin(\beta x))$.Look we got term which looks like $xsinx$ in our solution. In this case since there are four constants order is $4$.

Now,suppose we have complex root repeated thrice.Then,our solution will look like$e^{\alpha x}((C_1 + C_2 x +C_3 x^2)cos(\beta x)+(C_4 + C_5 x + C_6 x^2)sin(\beta x))$.Yeah,we got term $x^2sinx$ in solution.

And since there are $6$ constants present,answer is $\color\red 6$.